# How to "append" significant figures to double from float value

Tags: c#, double, rounding, floating-point-precision

Currently I am trying to match a C# and C++ application. On the C++ side, when there is a value, say:

```
const char* svalue = "554.1327";
```

When I use `sscanf`:

```
float x;
sscanf(svalue, "%f", &x);
```

`x` will equate to `554.13269`, i.e. it has "additional" significant figures, even though they may round to the same value. (I think this application uses a different `float` type which can hold more than 7 significant figures.)

I do not want to change the C++ side. I would like my seperate C# appliaction to do the same.

For example, if I have the float `23423.29`, I would like to convert it to `23423.289`, which is a `double` (since in C#, standard `float` has no more than 7 significant figures), then convert that `double` into a string.

I cannot seem to find a method to do this. Any ideas? Or do I have to create my own function or call into the same C++ function from the C# side…?

Answer (score 0):

Hi there is a temprary solution for your problem like

```
            Double d = 23423.29f;
        int a = 23423.29.ToString().Length;
        Console.WriteLine(d.ToString().Remove(++a));
```

which gives result

```
23423.289
```